# Is rsync idempotent?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync, sd-card

To my understanding one advantage of `rsync` over `cp` is that it doesn't actually transfer any data if it's already there.

I'm currently trying to restore a backup to my raspi's micro SD (after apt crashed and bricked the system) using the following command:

```
sudo rsync -ac --hard-links --delete --progress --human-readable --stats /mounted_partition_image/ /rootfs_of_pi/
```

And to check if it actually worked, I reran the command expecting to see no files transferred. However it still transferred 62 files

```
Number of files: 42.296 (reg: 32.469, dir: 3.907, link: 5.912, dev: 8)
Number of created files: 0
Number of deleted files: 0
Number of regular files transferred: 62
Total file size: 1,23G bytes
Total transferred file size: 256,43M bytes
Literal data: 256,43M bytes
Matched data: 0 bytes
File list size: 327,66K
File list generation time: 0,001 seconds
File list transfer time: 0,000 seconds
Total bytes sent: 258,09M
Total bytes received: 5,61K

sent 258,09M bytes  received 5,61K bytes  4,13M bytes/sec
total size is 1,23G  speedup is 4,75
```

I did this a few times more, the last time it only transferred ~10 files. I also checked with `diff -rq`, which also reported differences in a few large files.

Assuming a dying SD card I also ran one pass of `badblocks` with pattern `0xaa` without errors.

Is something wrong with my command or the sd card failing in some way not detected by `badblocks`?

Comment: Is it possible that files on either the source or destination filesystem tree were modified during or after each transfer process?